# Why is this AsyncImageView not loading the image?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I have the following code:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    AsyncImageView *weatherImageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:weatherImage.frame];
    NSString *myString = @"http://openweathermap.org/img/w/10d.png";
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithString:myString];
    NSLog(@"The complete url is %@", url);
    [weatherImageView loadImageFromURL:url];
    [self.weatherImage addSubview:weatherImageView];
}
```

The image URL is all fine but the image does not show up when the view appears.

But if I write the following line in the same method

```
-(void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated {
        [self.weatherImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[UIImage imageNamed:"background.png"]]];
}
```

I see that the image referred by "background.png" appears neat in the ImageView.

Wondering what is wrong with the first code.

Answer (score 1):

`loadImageFromURL` expects a NSURL. Not a NSString:

```
AsyncImageView *weatherImageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:weatherImage.frame];
NSString *myString = @"http://openweathermap.org/img/w/10d.png";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myString];
NSLog(@"The complete url is %@", url);
[weatherImageView loadImageFromURL:url];
```

Comment: It actually accepts a NSString itself. I see this in the code of ASyncImageView.m: //Download an image from a given URL or show it  if already downloaded
- (void)loadImageFromURL:(NSString*)url
{
 [self loadImageFromURL:url forceRedownload:NO]; 
}

Comment: Sorry, I see that I have a different AsyncImageView. I am looking into that.

Comment: Can you please point me to the library of AsyncView that actually has this method please?